# UK visa refusal reasons

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I applied for a UK visit visa and received a refusal; I don't know the reason. I was planning to do a tour starting with Switzerland, so I provided information of the tour. The answer was:

[image: Visa refusal letter]

I will apply again, but I don't understand the reason. What can I do? How much time do I have to wait to apply again?

Comment: To answer this question we need you to upload a scan of your refusal notice, with any personal information blacked out. Also, did the 'tour' that you provided information about include details of when and where you would be visiting in Britain?

Comment: If you told the immigration officer what you've told us it's far from clear why you are applying for a UK visa - Switzerland is a different country. You need to explain why you need to enter the UK if you're travelling to Switzerland. If you're just transitting at a UK airport you may not need a visa at all.

Comment: Does the tour "starting with Switzerland" also include travel to the UK?  If so, please tell us how that is reflected in the documents you submitted with your application.  If not (that is, if you plan a separate trip to the UK after the tour is over), then you *also* should have included a description of your planned travel to the UK, and it appears that you did not do so.

Comment: The answer is pretty clear, you know the reason. They are asking themselves "Why does he want to visit the UK if it seems that he spends most of the time in Switzerland? He says nothing about his plans.here. What does he want? Rejected" **Do not apply again until you have explained convincingly in detail what do you want in the UK or you will be blacklisted**.

Comment: Yes, the tour I plan to do starts in Switzerland, continues through Spain, Italy, France and later London, United Kingdom, but I will return to Spain to take the flight back to my country, the details I presented were the vouchers of the trip that I was given the travel agency, the list of reserved hotels with specific dates, round trip airline tickets and bank statements showing my economic solvency

Comment: Please edit the above information into the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally a good idea to apply for visas **backwards**.

If you already have a double-entry Schengen visa which allows you to go on the continental part of the tour, you don't have to supply too many details of that to the UK -- they can see that a Schengen state has looked into it.

The UK will also be reassured that you can legally go to the Schengen states, which makes it appear less likely that you'd overstay in the UK instead.